# How to join independant dataframes and get in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

What is the best way to achieve this:

```
test = pd.DataFrame([2,3,4])
test1 = test.copy()
test2 = test.copy()
test1['start'] = 2017
test1['end'] = 2018
test2['start'] = 2018
test2['end'] = 2019
test = pd.concat([test1, test2])
```

With the following result:

```
        0   start   end
    0   2   2017    2018
    1   3   2017    2018
    2   4   2017    2018
    0   2   2018    2019
    1   3   2018    2019
    2   4   2018    2019

I think there will be a more elegant way ;)
```

Update (full picture):

DataFrame1 columns: id, year, value
DataFrame2 columns: start, end

result: id, start, end, avg of value for each id in DataFrame1 and each start/end combination of DataFrame2

```
data:

id  year    value
1   2016    -0,232
1   2017    -0,432
1   2018    -0,532
1   2019    -0,632
1   2020    -0,682
2   2016    0,768
2   2017    0,568
2   2018    0,468
2   2019    0,368
2   2020    0,318
2   2021    0,268

start   end
2017    2018
2017    2019
2018    2019
```

result:

```
id  start   end avg_value
1   2017    2018    -0,48
1   2017    2019    -0,53
1   2018    2019    -0,58
2   2017    2018    0,52
2   2017    2019    0,47
2   2018    2019    0,42
```

The original question was to build up the result dataframe (as first step without the avg_value). It should calculate the average within the years where start and end is "included".

Comment: Maybe.. but what else are you going to do. What’s the reason/objective?

Comment: Basically my question is more generic. I will have a set of data and I will need to calculate results for different time ranges, e.g. 2017-2018, 2017-2019, 2017-2020. So the dataframe contains the columns id, year, value and I will need the averages for e.g. 2017-2018, 2017-2019 and so on and therefore I would have startet with my "result" in the question. There could be a weight as well, but I think I will now how to add that weight myself.

Comment: @bu22 - Can you edit answer? There are same output for different ranges in first column?

Comment: Share your "set of data" to understand better. Your question is too open.

Answer (score 2):

Use cross join first and then custom function:

```
df1['value'] = df1['value'].replace(',','.', regex=True).astype(float)

def f(x):
    return df1.loc[df1['year'].between(x['start'], x['end']) & 
                  (df1['id'] == x['id']), 'value'].mean()

df = (pd.merge(df1[['id']].drop_duplicates().assign(a=1), df2.assign(a=1), on='a')
       .drop('a',1))
df['avg_value'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
print (df)
   id  start   end  avg_value
0   1   2017  2018     -0.482
1   1   2017  2019     -0.532
2   1   2018  2019     -0.582
3   2   2017  2018      0.518
4   2   2017  2019      0.468
5   2   2018  2019      0.418
```

Comment: @Bharath The thing is... I knew the question was something else. Nobody wants what first was described :). Jezrael will surely make it anyway.

Comment: @jezrael: thank you, that solves my initial question (although I did not described it in a good way) perfectly!

Comment: @jezrael Hahahah this was messy indeed :) +1 anyway